# Wordpress strange permalinks

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

maybe anybody know why wordpress generate link like this: portfolio/all/**#.UHSbFy5mJIk**
I make bold the permalink strange place

I have no changes in wordpress core

Comment: Do you have any social sharing plugins enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have a sharing plugin enabled that is appending the extra stuff to your URL. This is tracking data to let you know how your links are being shared.